# htaccess not rewriting urls correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i've encountered the following problem:

The .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule view/^(.*)$ view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is not rewriting my urls

The friendly URL should be like this

https://domain.tld/view/1

And the original url should be rewritten like this:

https://domain.tld/view.php?id=1

The result of the htaccess above is a 404.

Comment: Try RewriteRule view/(.*)$ view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] at last line. I'vent tried it but as far as i know ^ is used to declare beggining of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$  view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Works. Thank you :)